# Github not detecting an inner index.html

Tags: github, http-status-code-404, github-pages

I'm publishing my own profile site on github on https://yilmazhasan.github.io/pwp

It was working before some changes, **now it gives 404** for https://yilmazhasan.github.io/pwp/src/index.html **although there is an index.html file.**

I'm redirecting pwp/index.html to pwp/src/index.html, it sees first one but not second one.

Since it is public, they can be seen on https://github.com/yilmazhasan/pwp

What can be caused to this?

(Note: It works on localhost)

Answer (score 1):

Even without redirecting pwp/index.html to pwp/src/index.html, you could simply change your [publication folder](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-server@2.20/github/working-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site#choosing-a-publishing-source) to `src`, as [seen here](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/working-with-github-pages/configuring-a-publishing-source-for-your-github-pages-site#choosing-a-publishing-source) (for the docs folder, but the same idea applies)

[image: https://docs.github.com/assets/images/help/pages/publishing-source-folder-drop-down.png]

Comment: Thank you @VonC, for indicating the erroneous part. I couldn't see the /src folder there and the way of adding it. However I solved by untransfering src folder outside of docs.